# How to update as3 code faster?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, frame, updates

Is it any way possible to update my code (as3) more than 1 time per frame? it doesnt have to do anything visual. I used before event.ENTER_FRAME. If there's a way to do so, could someone explain or give a link how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to update so often? If it's for something on the stage, updating more often won't make any difference since the stage only updates once a frame.

Comment: hitTestPoints colliding with objects

Comment: You can achieve far better results with CCD (Continuos Collision detection: https://www.google.com/search?q=Continuos+Collision+detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer to execute code at whatever rate you want :

```
 // first parameter for Timer is duration in milliseconds 1000ms = 1 second.
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10,0); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();


function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    // do something;
}
```

However, I'd question why you want to do this and determine if it's really needed.

Comment: Im trying to update hitTestPoints for a platformer game so my player wont go throught walls if the hitTestPoints wont update fast enough

PS: thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Hey it worked! many thanks for helping and here's my game. notice the difference between colliding the wall on right and left side.
http://www.mediafire.com/?182i8fj1yaakqhq

Comment: Great. Another approach would be doing multiple update/collision iterations in a frame. So if you get a time slice of say 30 milliseconds on a given frame, you'd do three 10s iterations in that frame. You'd have less events firing off with that method, but not sure if that's significant.

Answer (score 0):

If you app is running at 30fps you can set it to run at 60fps, then ENTER_FRAME will be called twice as much, or if you use a timer to update you can reduce its delay by half.

Comment: Yea I know but I want it to run even more densely than my framerate.

Comment: Then you have use a timer that is called twice as much.